# Clicking a button to display 5 more divs but only a max of 20 divs total should be shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have my JS code allow a user to click the "Show 5 More" button to display 5 more "content-section" divs, and disable the button when a total of 20 'content-section' divs are displayed. I'm unsure why my code is not working? I do not have the code for a max of 20 divs, I'm unsure where to place that.

HTML

```
<div class="content-section news-preview clearfix">
<div class="title">Title of News Article</div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/news_sample208x135.jpg" width="208" height="135">
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dui luctus lectus eget libero volupat, a tempor velit malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mattis egestas lorem a sodales.</p>
    </div>
</div>  <a class="article-link">http://www.lintothenewsarticle.com/news/article/title-of-news-article</a>
```

Show 5 More

JS

```
function showPreview () {

    if($('#show-more').on('click', function () {
        $('.content-section').append();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: after each append check divs.length >= 20

Comment: But my original JS code to append the divs is not working in the first place, I don't understand why

Comment: It is because you are not appending anything as you are not passing anything as a parameter. Check this link to see how to use append() http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

Comment: take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/895morrd/

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen example here.](http://codepen.io/michael-hamilton/pen/BNddye)

I would wrap all of the content-section divs inside of a div that you can append to.  Also add a show more button as such:

```
<div class="articles">
    <div class="content-section news-preview clearfix">
    <div class="title">Title of News Article</div>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="images/news_sample208x135.jpg" width="208" height="135">
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Dui luctus lectus eget libero volupat, a tempor velit malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mattis egestas lorem a sodales.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="article-link">http://www.lintothenewsarticle.com/news/article/title-of-news-article</a>
</div>

<a id="show-more" href="javascript:;">Show More</a>
```

In your Javascript, you check if the "Read More" button has been clicked.  Then you check if there are less than 20 `.content-section` divs inside of `<div class="articles">`.  If so then you can append what you want (change the content inside of the `append()` statement to whatever you want to append, just be sure that you follow the scheme where each article is wrapped in a div with a class of `content-section`.

```
$('#show-more').click(function(){ 
    if($('.articles > .content-section').length<20){
       $('.articles').append('<div class="content-section">a</div>');
    }
});
```